# How to make discord.py display the current week number with a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically I need the bot to display the current week when I do a command like `whatstheweek` and the bot displays for example `It is currently week 6.` I think this should be pretty easy to do but all the tutorials I found are for normal python and not discord.py and I'm not sure how to make it work for discord.py.

Comment: discord.py is python, evrything you can do in python works in discord.py

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, `discord.py` is an [API wrapper](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) made for python. You can use other python libraries on your bot.

For your question, you can use the `datetime` module.

You can get the week of the year like that with this module:

```
my_date = datetime.date.today() # if date is 01/01/2018
year, week_num, day_of_week = my_date.isocalendar()
print("Week #" + str(week_num) + " of year " + str(year))
```

This will give the **output**:

```
Week #3 of year 2022
```

**Full code:**

```
import discord
import datetime

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!whatstheweek'):
        my_date = datetime.date.today() # if date is 01/01/2018
        year, week_num, day_of_week = my_date.isocalendar()
        
        await message.channel.send("Week #" + str(week_num) + " of year " + str(year))

client.run('your token here')
```